# How to clear KML layer infowindow properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a couple of kml layers loaded on my google map. I've attached a click event to the kml layer to display it's info and i've also added some other content to the infowindow. My issue is if I click the layer for the second time, the added content gets repeated. This is my code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layers[2], 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
 latlongkml = kmlEvent.latLng.toString();
 var text = kmlEvent.featureData.name;
 station = text;
 kmlEvent.featureData.infoWindowHtml += '<p>'+latlongkml+'</p><br/><button onclick="kmladd()" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Add to Route</button>';
showInContentWindow(text);

 });

function showInContentWindow(text) {
var div = document.getElementById('content-window');
 }
```

Then it looks like this if i click on it twice:

[image]

I've tried to clear the content like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layers[2], 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
 latlongkml = kmlEvent.latLng.toString();
 var text = kmlEvent.featureData.name;
 station = text;
 kmlEvent.featureData.infoWindowHtml = ('');
 kmlEvent.featureData.infoWindowHtml += '<p>'+latlongkml+'</p><br/><button onclick="kmladd()" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Add to Route</button>';
showInContentWindow(text);

 });
```

But then my heading disappears:

[image]

Here is a JSFiddle of the issue.
https://jsfiddle.net/rdawkins/82ks7xvp/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't overwrite the KmlLayer `kmlEvent.featureData.infoWindow` data, suppress the native infowindows and create your own infowindow using that data:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var kmlOptions = { map: map, suppressInfoWindows: true};
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl, kmlOptions);
google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
  latlongkml = kmlEvent.latLng.toString();
  var text = kmlEvent.featureData.name;
  station = text;
  var htmlContent = kmlEvent.featureData.infoWindowHtml + '<p>'+latlongkml+'</p><br/><button onclick="kmladd()" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Add to Route</button>';
  infowindow.setOptions({content: htmlContent,
    pixelOffset: kmlEvent.pixelOffset,
    position: kmlEvent.latLng})
    infowindow.open(map);
}):
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/82ks7xvp/9/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function display_kmlmap() {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var map_options = {};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), map_options);
  var kmlUrl = 'http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/static/red.kml';
  var kmlOptions = {
    map: map,
    suppressInfoWindows: true
  };

  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl, kmlOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
    latlongkml = kmlEvent.latLng.toString();
    var text = kmlEvent.featureData.name;
    station = text;
    var htmlContent = kmlEvent.featureData.infoWindowHtml + '<p>' + latlongkml + '</p><br/><button onclick="kmladd()" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Add to Route</button>';
    infowindow.setOptions({
      content: htmlContent,
      pixelOffset: kmlEvent.pixelOffset,
      position: kmlEvent.latLng
    })
    infowindow.open(map);
  })

}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<title>Google Maps API v3 : KML Layer</title>

<body onload="display_kmlmap()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:400px; float:left">
  </div>
</body>
```